# Can not get data from two tables

Tags: sql

This code:

```
SELECT *
FROM pc,usb
WHERE CATEGORIES like %s
    or NAMEOFTHEPRODUCTSSHORT like %s
    or NAMEOFTHEPRODUCTS like %s
    or INFOPRODUCTS like %s
    or INFOPRODUCTSPRICE like %s
    or INFOPRODUCTSPRICEOFSHIP like %s
    or INFOPRODUCTSPRICEOFALL like %s
    or TABINFOPRODUCTS like %s
```

Returns this error message:

> Column 'CATEGORIES' in where clause is ambiguous

How can I get data from two tables?

Comment: Do your pc and usb tables both have a categories field?

Comment: Are you trying to select data from the pc table or the usb table? If you want data from both you will have to join them somehow

Comment: Yes both Have the same thing

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 2):

Your both tables have a column named `categories`. You should get each of them like below:

```
pc.CATEGORIES as pcCategories, usb.CATEGORIES as usbCategories
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM pc,usb
WHERE TABLE_NAME.CATEGORIES like %s
```

This is something you should do..add table name with column name

to be more specific

```
WHERE pc.CATEGORIES like %s OR usb.CATEGORIES like %s
```

My recommendation would be to use `table_name.column_name` to

- avoid error
- better performance